# Javascript Constructor vs Object Literal Confusion

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I recently came across constructors for creating multiple objects with the same properties and methods.

**Method 1:**

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name =  name;
}
```

And then you can instantiate it like so:

```
var bob = new Person("bob");
```

What i would like to know is there a difference between using the standard constructor method and just returning an object inside a function like so:

**Method 2:**

```
function Person(name) {
  var obj = {
    name:  name,
  };
  return obj;
}
```

I am still able to create multiple objects using the same function. I am just slightly confused on why you would use 'Method 1'? Is it because i can extend the first method using the prototype property? Am i able to extend and create more methods using 'Method 2'?

Am i right in thinking this is why you use constructors because they are more flexible and can be added to and modified whereas the Object literal type inside a function cannot? Also what other benefits does it bring?

Sorry if this is a silly question.

Thanks, any information would be nice

Comment: tldr; returning from a ctor returns *that* value (in this case, an object created *inside* the ctor). Semantically, a ctor that does not have any value explicitly returned can be thought of as having an implicit `return this;`. The primary resulting-object difference in the question is thus between an object *created* view `new` (eg. `this` is ctor).. and objects that are created via literals.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the one it is marked a duplicate of!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
  function Person(name) { /* either of your approaches */}

  Person.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name; 
  }
```

Method 1 will work as expected, method 2 will not, if you call:

```
  new Person('Bob').getName ()
```

Comment: You should have added a more complete answer. E.g what if I were to say `obj.getName = function() {
return this.name};` ? To the naked eye, it would look as if it were the exact same thing as the example you provided.